# web app is sharing the same memory storage

Tags: project-management

I working in a app that i use to compute user details. But somehow, the values of a user alter that of another user. Below is a fragment of the code

```
def Compute_UserScore(self, details, ques_no):
    try:
        if(HomePage.answer_.strip() == ""):
            self.response.write("""<script type = "text/javascript">
            alert("Dear User, You can not answer same answer twice.. Take test Again !");
            </script>""")
            self.redirect('/otherPages/subjectSelect.html')
        else:
            count = 0
            HomePage.ans_no = 0
            HomePage.unans_no = 0
            HomePage.correct_no = 0
            HomePage.wrong_no = 0
            HomePage.failed_ques = list()
            HomePage.answer_ = HomePage.answer_.strip()
            question_1 = HomePage.question_.split(" gcdc_split_format ")
            while (count != (ques_no)):
                user_answer = str(details[count]).strip().capitalize()
                real_answer = str(HomePage.answer_[count]).strip().capitalize()
                if (len(str(user_answer).strip()) == 1):
                    HomePage.ans_no = HomePage.ans_no + 1
                    if(user_answer.strip() == real_answer.strip()):
                        HomePage.correct_no = HomePage.correct_no + 1
                    else:
                        HomePage.wrong_no = HomePage.wrong_no + 1
                        HomePage.failed_ques.append(str("No. " + str(int((count + 1))) + "  " + str(question_1[count])))
                else:
                    HomePage.unans_no = HomePage.unans_no + 1
                count = count + 1
            HomePage.answer_ = ""
    except:
        self.redirect('/')
    return " "
```

and this is how my homepage looks like

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    percentage = None
    subject_answered = None
    username_ = None
    email_ = None
    super_date = None
    answer_ = " "
    question_ = " "
    failed_ques = list()
    wrong_no = 0
    correct_no = 0
    ans_no = 0
    unans_no = 0
```

The problem is, when a user A, take a test, He sees the result of another user B. Read about Using instance variable, but still have not figure ouut how to make it work